# inequality $(a+b+c+d)(a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3) > (a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2$

Tags: inequality

I am trying to prove the inequality:

$$(a+b+c+d)(a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3) > (a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2$$ given $a,b,c,d$ are positive and unequal.

starting from LHS

since AM of mth power > mth power of AM

$$(a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3)/4 > ((a+b+c+d)/4)^3$$

multiplying both sides by $(a+b+c+d)$

$$(a+b+c+d)(a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3)/4 > (a+b+c+d)^4/(4^3)$$

$\implies$
 $$(a+b+c+d)(a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3) > (a+b+c+d)^4/16$$

now taking expression on the RHS and using AM of mth power > mth power of AM

$$(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)/4 > ((a+b+c+d)/4)^2$$

squaring both sides

$$(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2/16 > (a+b+c+d)^4/(4^4)$$

$$\implies (a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2 > ((a+b+c+d)^4)/16$$

Now I have proved that both LHS and RHS are greater than  $$((a+b+c+d)^4)/16$$

still unable to prove LHS > RHS. Please help with this.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Use Cauchy inequality: $$(x_1+x_2+...+x_n)(y_1+y_2+...+y_n)\geq (\sqrt{x_1y_1}+...+\sqrt{x_ny_n})^2$$

Comment: Thanks very much , that nailed the problem is a single statement , amazing.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You will get the left-hand side minus the right-hand side:
$${a}^{3}b+{a}^{3}c+{a}^{3}d-2\,{a}^{2}{b}^{2}-2\,{a}^{2}{c}^{2}-2\,{a}^
{2}{d}^{2}+a{b}^{3}+a{c}^{3}+a{d}^{3}+{b}^{3}c+{b}^{3}d-2\,{b}^{2}{c}^
{2}-2\,{b}^{2}{d}^{2}+b{c}^{3}+b{d}^{3}+{c}^{3}d-2\,{c}^{2}{d}^{2}+c{d
}^{3}
$$ Now you need to combine like terms:
$$a^3b-2a^2b^2+ab^2=ab(a^2-2ab+b^2)$$ and so on.

Comment: Thanks very much , got it.